# How to retrieve the latest message (event) from IoT Hub, by device, via HTTP

Tags: azure, http, synchronous, azure-iot-hub

I have found many examples on how to retrieve  data from a running IoT hub. However, in all of these, some variant of [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket?wprov=sfla1) is required.

- [AMQP](https://www.amqp.org/)
- The JavaScript Client SDK, with this sample in a [web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-live-data-visualization-in-web-apps)
- There is even a [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/), but it's only for managing devices and *sending* data.

**I need a way to immediately get the latest message available from an IoT device.**

## Scenario

I am running a small weather station using 4 devices, which send their data to the IoT hub. As a display, I want to recycle a [1st generation iPad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPad_%281st_generation%29?wprov=sfla1). It's browser does not support WebSockets, thus ruling out all the modern approaches.

I will update the values with polling, preferably using simple HTTP GET requests, every 15 minutes.

I have the above mentioned sample running (qrysweathertest.azurewebsites.net), but it uses web sockets, thus not working on a 1stGen iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible out of the box with IoT Hub. You will have to store the telemetry values to storage (a database for instance), and build a small API to retrieve the latest value. You could store and retrieve the values using Azure Functions, which would be a low-cost way to enable your scenario.

Alternatively, IoT Central does support retrieving the latest telemetry value through the [inbuilt API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iotcentral/devices/gettelemetryvalue?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034). And possibly the dashboarding features of IoT Central can cover your entire scenario.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning IoT Central. I did not know about it. It's probably a bit too involved for my hobby project, so I am going to look into Azure Functions first.

Comment: For hobby projects I usually start with IoT Central (it leverages IoT Hub behind the scenes), but it's not always the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative for your hobby project can be considered to use a device twin **tags** property for storing the last telemetry data.

Basically, you can use the *EventGridTrigger* subscriber for storing the telemetry data to the device twin tags property in the **push manner** or using the **pull manner** for instance, the *IoTHubTrigger* function as a consumer of the iothub stream pipeline.

The following code snippet shows an example of the *IoTHubTrigger* function:

run.csx:

```cs
#r "Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs"
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "..\\bin\\Microsoft.Azure.Devices.dll"
#r "..\\bin\\Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared.dll"


using Microsoft.Azure.Devices;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Text;

static RegistryManager registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureIoTHubShariedAccessPolicy"));

public static async Task Run(EventData message, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"\nSystemProperties:\n\t{string.Join(" | ", message.SystemProperties.Select(i => $"{i.Key}={i.Value}"))}");

    if (message.SystemProperties["iothub-message-source"]?.ToString() == "Telemetry")
    {    
        var connectionDeviceId = message.SystemProperties["iothub-connection-device-id"].ToString(); 
        var msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body.Array);
        
        log.LogInformation($"DeviceId = {connectionDeviceId}, Telemetry = {msg}");

        var twinPatch = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { tags = new { telemetry = new { lastUpdated = message.SystemProperties["iothub-enqueuedtime"], data = JObject.Parse(msg) }}});
        await registryManager.ReplaceTwinAsync(connectionDeviceId, twinPatch, "*");
    }
}
```

function.json:

```cs
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "message",
      "connection": "my_IOTHUB",
      "eventHubName": "my_IOTHUB_NAME",
      "consumerGroup": "function",
      "cardinality": "one",
      "direction": "in",
      "type": "eventHubTrigger"
    }
  ]
}
```

Once, the telemetry data are stored in the device twin tags property, we can use all iothub built-in features for querying and retrieving the device twins programmatically or using the azure portal.

The following example shows a query string to obtain the telemetry data from all devices:

```
SELECT devices.id, devices.tags.telemetry FROM devices WHERE is_defined(devices.tags.telemetry)
```

Using the [REST Get Devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/devices/getdevices) we can get the result of the query string, see the following example:

[image]

and using the [REST Get Twin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/devices/gettwin) we can get the device twin for specific device, see the following example:

[image]

*Notes:*

1. the REST request requires a sas token for *Authorization* header
2. the above solution is not suitable for Basic Tier IoT Hub (doesn't have a device twin)
3. usage of this solution is fine for a hobby project (Free and S1 pricing tiers), in the case of more hundreds devices with a frequently ingestion of the telemetry data, please refer to the [IoT Hub quotas and throttling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling) document about the throttles on the *Queries* and *Twin updates*.